# How can I compact the code defining the list of validatees and validators in ReactiveFormsModule of Angular?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript, angular-forms

I have form validation based on *ReactiveFormsModule* as follows. In reality, there's quite a few more validatees and the list of validators for each is longer (although basically the same for each).

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = builder.group({
    "firstName": ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    "lastName": ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
  });
}
```

It bothers me that it's so verbose and I wonder if there's a neat way to smash all the validators together and let there be one, single instance of it, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see, you've got two dimensions of bother - the set of fields to be validated (vertical size) and the set of validations (horizontal size)? While @n00dl3 discuss (and criticizes) cutting in both dimensions, I strongly suggest that you only work on the latter (i.e. horizontal).

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  const validation = [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)];
  this.form = builder.group({
    "firstName": ["", validation],
    "lastName": ["", validation]
  });
}
```

Furthermore, I suspect that you'll hit the point where parameterized validations are require. In such case, you might consider switching to a function that brings out the appropriate validations.

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = builder.group({
    "firstName": ["", validation(1)],
    "lastName": ["", validation(2)]
  });
}

validation(type: number) : Validations {
  if(type === 1)
    return [Validations.required];
  return [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fields do have the same validators you can just use an array for your keys and reduce it like this :

```
const fields=["firstName","lastName"]
let myGroup = fields.reduce((group,field)=>{
  return group[field]=["",[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3)]]
},{} as {[k:string]:any});

this.form = builder.group(myGroup);
```

If some field has different validator you can even set if afterward:

```
this.form.get("myField").setValidators([someValidator]);
```

But note that IMHO you lose readability.